# Ignorar cabeçalho do CSV antes de inserir no banco

Tags: php

criei um método para fazer upload de clientes via arquivos csv. Está funcionando perfeitamente o cadastro, no entanto eu preciso ignorar a primeira linha, o cabeçalho do arquivo, estou procurando mas ainda não conseguir uma solução. Se alguém puder sugerir uma ideia.

```
  public function uploadDados(array $dados) {
       $this->dados = $dados;
       if(!empty($this->dados)){
          if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
             while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE ){
                 if($this->verificaDados($data[0])) {
                    $query = $this->conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO tb_clients (id, codigo_cliente, nome_cliente, tentativas, data_venda, prioridade, data_limite, produto, status_id, timed_expirado) VALUES (null, :codigo_cliente, :nome_cliente, :tentativas, :data_venda, :prioridade, :data_limite, :produto, :status_id, :timed_expirado)");
                    $limite = $this->countDays($data[3]);
                    $query->bindParam(':codigo_cliente', $data[0]);
                    $query->bindParam(':nome_cliente', $data[1]);
                    $query->bindParam(':tentativas', $data[2]);
                    $query->bindParam(':data_venda', $data[3]);
                    $query->bindParam(':prioridade', $data[4]);
                    $query->bindParam(':data_limite', $limite);
                    $query->bindParam(':produto', $data[6]);
                    $query->bindParam(':status_id', $data[7]);
                    $query->bindParam(':timed_expirado', $data[8]);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->resultado = TRUE;
                  } 
             }
            fclose($handle);
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Em qual linha do seu código você começa a percorrer o arquivo linha a linha?

Comment: $this->verificaDados($data[0]) // Verifica se o cliente não existe no banco e retorna true

Comment: E o que o `verificaDados` faz atualmente se, pelo o que comentou, não está verificando o dado?

Comment: verificaDados faz um select no banco antes de inserir  um novo cliente caso o número de linhas afetada seja maior ou igual a 1 então retorna FALSE. Retornando false não faz a inserção do registro que já existe no banco.

Comment: Já adianto que isso é uma prática ruim, afetando não só a performance como gerando um problema de condição de corrida. Ao invés disso, busque adicionar a coluna como índice único no banco e trate os erros durante a inserção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode simplesmente fazer uma checagem com true e false:

```
 $primeiro = true;


 while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE ){
     if($this->verificaDados($data[0])) {

        //Se true (primeira vez) executa o "continue;" que pula para a proxima linha do CSV
        //Se false não entra no IF, após o primeiro loop irá setar como false
        if ($primeiro) {
            $primeiro = false;
            continue;
        }

        $query = $this->conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO tb_clients (id, codigo_cliente, nome_cliente, tentativas, data_venda, prioridade, data_limite, produto, status_id, timed_expirado) VALUES (null, :codigo_cliente, :nome_cliente, :tentativas, :data_venda, :prioridade, :data_limite, :produto, :status_id, :timed_expirado)");
        $limite = $this->countDays($data[3]);
        $query->bindParam(':codigo_cliente', $data[0]);
        $query->bindParam(':nome_cliente', $data[1]);
        $query->bindParam(':tentativas', $data[2]);
        $query->bindParam(':data_venda', $data[3]);
        $query->bindParam(':prioridade', $data[4]);
        $query->bindParam(':data_limite', $limite);
        $query->bindParam(':produto', $data[6]);
        $query->bindParam(':status_id', $data[7]);
        $query->bindParam(':timed_expirado', $data[8]);
        $query->execute();
        $this->resultado = TRUE;
      } 
 }
```

Você também pode checar se o código do cliente é em um formato válido dentro da propria função `verificaDados()`, por exemplo se só aceita números então quando for o header provavelmente não será numérico, algo como:

```
private verificaDados($codigo) {
    if (ctype_digit(trim($codigo)) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    ... código que verifica se já existe no banco de dados ...
}
```

E desta forma nem precisaria desta parte:

```
if ($primeiro) {
    $primeiro = false;
    continue;
}
```

Nota: a função `ctype_digit` verifica se são numeros apenas, é semelhante ao `is_numeric`, mas não aceita o formato com ponto e nem números negativos, o que é o ideal para os seus "IDs", supondo que use números neles.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou !  Agradecido @Guilherme Nascimento